# Try/Except 'caching' requests

Tags: python

My function seems to be "caching" requests

```
def myFunction(main_dict, data1, data2):
   
    #Send to server
    json_to_send =json.dumps(main_dict)

    try:
        import requests
        r = requests.post("http://localhost/insert.php", data = {'data1': data1, "data2": data2}, headers = {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
        if r.text == 'OK':
            print("Received by server")
        else:
            print("Server error. Try again")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error to send")
        return
```

**The problem is**: If goes to `except` 3 times, for example, when I send the fourth request and it goes right, it will send the current one 4 times to the server

I appreciate any help

**UPDATE**: `myFunction` runs multiple times even it goes right. It's called by a button click. First click: Run 1 time. Second click: Run 2 times, etc

Comment: requests exception does not always mean the request was not received by the server

Comment: Ok, but, why it send the current request several times? I use the term "caching" but I'm not sure exactly why the code do it

Comment: `requests` won't resend by itself. There must be some retry algorithm in the outer code for `myFunction`

Comment: This is function is called by ```button.clicked.connect(myFunction)```. At every click, it run 2,3,4 times... I don't know what is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on other part of the code

The call for this function was inside a condition that, when satisfied again, runs the `.connect` again, so the function executed multiple times

```
//Satisfied multiple times

if action == 'main_action':
            MessageBox.show()
            messagebox_ui.buttonSendMessageBox.clicked.connect(myFunction)
```

Solved it by disconnecting the button  using `.disconnect` inside `myFunction`

```
def myFunction(main_dict, data1, data2):
   
    #Send to server
    json_to_send =json.dumps(main_dict)

    try:
        import requests
        r = requests.post("http://localhost/insert.php", data = {'data1': data1, "data2": data2}, headers = {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
        if r.text == 'OK':
            print("Received by server")
            messagebox_ui.buttonSendMessageBox.clicked.disconnect(myFunction)

        else:
            print("Server error. Try again")
            messagebox_ui.buttonSendMessageBox.clicked.disconnect(myFunction)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error to send")
        messagebox_ui.buttonSendMessageBox.clicked.disconnect(myFunction)
```

I'm starting with Python and maybe my code don't follow the "standards", but it solved for me